# Setting a variable in a Makefile recipe and then testing it

Tags: makefile

In this recipe, I want git to fetch the current sha1 hash only if git is present and I'm in a git repository.  My problem is that $(GIT) is always null.  I don't understand why this is so yet setting $(HASH) and echoing it works.  What's going on here?  How can I get the Make to execute a chunk of code only if git is installed?

```
hash:
ifneq ("$(wildcard .git)", "")
    $(eval GIT=`which git`)
  ifdef $(GIT)
    $(eval HASH=`git rev-parse HEAD`)
    @echo $(HASH)
    @echo "#define GIT_SHA1 \"$(HASH)\"" > git_sha1.h
  endif
else
    @echo "Not in a git repository"
endif
```

I want to avoid having to use a shell script to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want git to fetch the current sha1 hash only if git is present and I'm in a git repository

You could do so like:

**Makefile 1**

```
HASH := $(if $(and $(wildcard .git),$(shell which git)), \
    $(shell git rev-parse HEAD))

hash:
ifdef HASH
    @echo $(HASH)
    @echo "#define GIT_SHA1 \"$(HASH)\"" > git_sha1.h
else
    @echo "Git not installed or not in a git repository"
endif
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
7cf328b322f7764144821fdaee170d9842218e36
```

when in a git repository (with at least one commit) and when not in a git repository
runs like:

```
$ make
Git not installed or not in a git repository
```

See [8.4 Functions for Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html)

Notice the contrast between:

```
ifdef HASH
```

and in your own attempt:

```
ifdef $(GIT)
```

The first tests if `HASH` is a defined (i.e. non-empty) make-variable, which is what I
want. The second tests if `$(GIT)`, i.e. the *value* of `GIT`, which you were hoping would be `which git`,
is a defined make variable. That is not what you want. `which git` isn't a defined make-variable, even if `GIT`
is, and:

```
ifdef `which git`
```

would be a sytax error<sup>[1]</sup>.

Presumably you have no real need for:

```
    @echo $(HASH)
```

In that case you could simplify to:

**Makefile 2**

```
hash:
ifneq ($(and $(wildcard .git),$(shell which git)),)
    @echo "#define GIT_SHA1 \"$$(git rev-parse HEAD)\"" > git_sha1.h
else
    @echo "Git not installed or not in a git repository"
endif
```

---

[1] So why don't you see any syntax error from `ifdef $(GIT)`? Because `GIT`
is not = `which git` in this context. It is undefined. The following
makefile illustrates:

**Makefile 3**

```
GLOBAL_VAR_A := global_var_a
all:
    $(eval RECIPE_VAR_A=recipe_var_a)
ifdef RECIPE_VAR_A
    @echo $(RECIPE_VAR_A) for RECIPE_VAR_A 
else
    @echo RECIPE_VAR_A is defined only within the recipe
endif
ifdef GLOBAL_VAR_A
    @echo GLOBAL_VAR_A is defined globally
    @echo $(RECIPE_VAR_A) for GLOBAL_VAR_A
endif
```

Run:

```
$ make
RECIPE_VAR_A is defined only within the recipe
GLOBAL_VAR_A is defined globally
recipe_var_a for GLOBAL_VAR_A
```

Comment: Why does the first suggestion result in a leading space in the hash string as it appears in `git_sha1.h`?

Comment: @Frotz Ah, it's because of the way I line-split the definition of HASH to format for SO.
Make it `HASH := $(if $(and $(wildcard .git),$(shell which git)),$(shell git rev-parse HEAD))`
and there'll be no leading space.